# How start the nao_camera node?

Tags: python, camera, nao, nao-driver, camera-info-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

$ I am able to use the Python Nodes with the robot NAO using:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/path/to/pynaoqi/"
```

and

```
$ roslaunch nao_driver nao_driver.launch force_python:=true nao_ip:=192.168.1.206
```

if I want to check which nodes are running:

```
$ rosnode list
```

and I obtained the next list:

```
/nao_behaviors
/nao_controller
/nao_leds
/nao_sensors
/nao_speech
/nao_tactile
/nao_walker
```

How can I start or launch the nao_camera, because I going to need the image since i work in Computer Vision? I tried with:

```
$ roslaunch nao_driver nao_camera.launch nao_ip:=192.168.1.206
```

but I got the next error:  (copy-paste of the terminal)

pablo@pabloNao:~$ roslaunch nao_driver nao_camera.launch force_python:=true nao_ip:=192.168.1.206
... logging to /home/pablo/.ros/log/1340b312-b510-11e3-9391-24b6fd11a455/roslaunch-pabloNao-6138.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://pabloNao:33756/

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /nao_camera/calibration_file_bottom
- /nao_camera/calibration_file_top
- /nao_camera/color_space
- /nao_camera/fps
- /nao_camera/resolution
- /rosdistro
- /rosversion

NODES
/
nao_camera (nao_driver/nao_camera.py)

ROS_MASTER_URI=XXX

## core service [/rosout] found
process[nao_camera-1]: started with pid [6156]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/nao_driver/nao_camera.py", line 38, in 
import camera_info_manager
ImportError: No module named camera_info_manager
================================================================================REQUIRED process [nao_camera-1] has died!
process has died [pid 6156, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nao_driver/nao_camera.py --pip=192.168.1.206 --pport=9559 __name:=nao_camera __log:=/home/pablo/.ros/log/1340b312-b510-11e3-9391-24b6fd11a455/nao_camera-1.log].
log file: /home/pablo/.ros/log/1340b312-b510-11e3-9391-24b6fd11a455/nao_camera-1*.log
Initiating shutdown!

[nao_camera-1] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
pablo@pabloNao:~$

I will really appreciate any advise, thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/144531/how-start-the-nao_camera-node?/) by [PabloM](https://answers.ros.org/users/13261/pablom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2014-03-26**:
Well, what's the error?

**Comment by [PabloM](https://answers.ros.org/users/13261/pablom/) on 2014-03-26**:
"No module named camera_info_manager". Is it correct the way I'm launching the nao_camera node? or I need to past some extra parameters?

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2014-03-26**:
Install the camera_info_manager_py package, e.g. "sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-camera-info-manager-py" for ROS Hydro. Did you manually check out the Nao packages or used the released pre-compiled versions (which should already install the dependency)?

**Comment by [PabloM](https://answers.ros.org/users/13261/pablom/) on 2014-03-26**:
I'm using the pre-compiled packages (sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-nao-robot) and not was installed the "camera-info-manager-py just the "camera-info-manager". And now with the image_view I can watch the retrieved image. Thank you so much Armin!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To summarize the answer from the comments (in case someone runs into the same problem): The Python camera driver node in `nao_driver` requires the package `camera_info_manager_py`. You can install it in ROS hydro with `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-camera-info-manager-py`

The dependency was missing in the package.xml, I'll fix that for the next release.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2014-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0